# Foreign Key Constraint (Relationship) with assembled primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The following example is used to explain what I want to achieve. Consider a Table with users, and another one with topics. Each user should be able to rate each topic (once), but is not required to rate every topic. These are exemplary tables for the example:

```
CREATE TABLE [Topic](
    [topicID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [topic] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Topic] PRIMARY KEY(topicID))

CREATE TABLE [User](
    [userID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY(userID))

CREATE TABLE [Vote](
    [topicID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [userID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [vote] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Vote] PRIMARY KEY 
([topicID],[userID]))
```

The primary key `PK_Vote` is chosen in order to specify a constraint, that each user might only vote up to one time for each topic. 
Is there any way to specify a foreign key constraint (a relationship) using this assembled primary key? As far as I understand I can only reference a key at whole, so this isn't possible, as each part (column) of the key should match the primary key of a different table.

I want to this SQL Server 2008.

Comment: the primary key constraint on the `Vote` table will guarantee uniqueness.  You can define 2 separate foreign key constraints for `topicId` and `userId`.

Comment: If you want to create a FK relationship to `Vote`, you will need to use **both** columns defined in the PK for `Vote` - your child table will need **both** `TopicID` and `UserID`. There's no way to reference half a PK... - it's either **ALL** columns involved, or no FK relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that create vote table with identity column, and add unique index in order to restrict to insert duplicate record, and create foreign key constraint for user and topic tables.

```
CREATE TABLE [Vote](
    VoteId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [topicID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [userID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [vote] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Vote] PRIMARY KEY ([VoteId]))
 GO

 CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UX_Vote ON dbo.Vote(TopicID, UserID)
 ALTER TABLE [Vote] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Vote_Topic FOREIGN KEY(TopicID) REFERENCES dbo.Topic(TopicID)
 ALTER TABLE [Vote] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Vote_User FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES dbo.[User](UserID)
```